# Android menu view, gridview or something else?

Tags: android, gridview

I need to create a home screen (menu) with four to six items arranged in a grid view, each item needs to have an icon and a text below the icon. I googled and everything I could find were adapterView examples, with dynamic menu loading, and I want to make it with static xml, this view will not change so no need for dynamic code.

Can anyone post an xml example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a table layout.. [The layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) developer documentation has an example of an all xml way to configure it.